# download file using SSH in putty in windows operation system

Tags: ssh, putty

How do you copy file from Remote to your local computer in Windows using Putty.

```
scp -r username@remote:/path/to/folder /dest/local/path
```

I tried this but what would I write in place of `/dest/local/path` - is it `/D:/download/`?

I am confuse about it? Could some one help me it.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for Windows paths is the generally the same regardless of the application being used, provided it is run from cmd or the gui.

So your command would be

```
scp -r username@remote:/path/to/folder d:\download\
```

Comment: I get "Address 000.000.000.000 maps to mirrorone, but this does not map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!" 

And also after i put password, i it says 
"ssh: d: Name or service not known"

I am Using Putty for SSH connection.

Comment: @AnilPrajapati How does this relate to your question?  If you want to extend the scope of your original question, please edit it and add any additional detail